# NullReferenceException on SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse

Tags: c#, soap, xamarin, mono, xamarin.mac

I'm using Xamarin.mac and mono (4.6.2) to deploy a .Net application to macOS and Linux. This application uses the VirtualBox SDK which is provided through a SOAP webservice.

On Windows and Linux this works fine but on macOS I get a strange NullReferenceException when I try to invoke any method on the SOAP webservice.

The Stacktrace is:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage message, System.Net.WebResponse response, System.IO.Stream responseStream, System.Boolean asyncCall) [0x00398] in <4493f371b365451c969f031cecf97807>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] parameters) [0x0005d] in <4493f371b365451c969f031cecf97807>:0 
  at vboxBinding.IWebsessionManager_logon (System.String username, System.String password) [0x00001] in <908974d32d214cf186212716ae292b73>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) vboxBinding:IWebsessionManager_logon (string,string)
```

The called method:

```
[SoapDocumentMethod("", RequestNamespace = "http://www.virtualbox.org/", ResponseNamespace = "http://www.virtualbox.org/", Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute]
public string IWebsessionManager_logon([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute] string username, [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute] string password);
```

And the bindings:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[GeneratedCode("wsdl", "4.6.1055.0")]
[WebServiceBinding(Name = "vboxBinding", Namespace = "http://www.virtualbox.org/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerAssemblyAttribute(AssemblyName = "VBoxService.XmlSerializers")]
public class vboxBinding : SoapHttpClientProtocol
```

Of course this works fine on my development machine and only breaks on any other one so I think there must me some kind of dependency problem. The web service is reachable on the machines where the error occurs (as localhost).

Comment: Have you enabled diagnostics with verbose logging on the response to get some add'l detail?

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: I'm using mono 4.6.2 (I have edited the question).

How could I enable diagnostics for network traffic? Unfortunately this does not happen on the development machine...

Comment: are you using the same version on mono on Linux and Mac?

Comment: Yes the same mono version is used in both cases.